# When I build in Unity. I get an error called "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebSocketSharp' could not be found"

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Version: 2019.4.9f1

Error:
Assets\Scripts\GirisEkranYoneticisi.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebSocketSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

https://prnt.sc/urzjh9

Comment: What you have tried to fix this?

Comment: I tried to delete other namespaces but didn't work, also I need those too so I need a real solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in your code, its because mostly you are missing

> websocket-sharp.dll

You need to download it and drop it into Asset/Plugins.

Hope this solves your issue